# a way to make logging instance variables more DRY in ruby?

Tags: ruby, logging, dry

I am logging when in development mode, but am finding sometimes I have more code for logging than the code itself.

As I would debug issues, I realized I needed to make the logs more verbose so I knew what was going on.

But then I end up with something like this:

```
    json_log      =  {:replace_hash => @replace_hash}
    logger.info json_log.to_json

    json_log      =  {:outbound_text => @outbound_text}
    logger.info  json_log.to_json

    json_log      =  {:xtest => @xtest_array}
    logger.info  json_log.to_json

    json_log      =  {:tags => @tag_hash.keys, :last_response => @last_response }
    logger.info   json_log.to_json


    @json_event = { :bot_client_id => @bot_client_id,
                    :that          => @that,
                    :topic         => @topic,
                    :input         => @inbound_text,
                    :last_response => @last_response,
                    :via           => @via
                  }

    send_to_amplitude

    json_log = {:conversation => {:inbound_text => @inbound_text, :outbound_text => @outbound_text}}
    logger.debug json_log.to_s

    Keen.publish(:bot_response_run, @json_event)
```

Comment: What is your question?  How does the code above not satisfy you?

Comment: Since your are in development mode, you can use `pry` binding for debugging. If it is not enough then give more information what you exactly wanting.

Comment: Or `byebug`, which is based on `pry` and more friendly for debugging.

Comment: I currently use byebug, maybe I'm not using it properly -- I want to send to the logs values for debugging...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind - your hash keys quite often are same as instance variables, so you could have a logger class that will assume it needs to log a hash of instance variables

```
class MyLogger
  def initialize(rails_logger, context)
    @loger = rails_logger
    @context = context
  end

  def log(*args)
    @logger.info(extract_data(*args).to_json)
  end

  def log_with_prefix(prefix, *args)
    @logger.debug({ prefix: extract_data(*args) }.to_s)
  end    

  private

  def extract_data(*args)
    args.reduce({}) do |result, variable|
      result[variable] = extract_value(variable)
      result
    end
  end

  def extract_value(variable)
    name, method = variable.to_s.split('.')
    method.present? ? context.instance_variable_get("@#{name}") : context.instance_variable_get("@#{variable}").public_send(method)
  end       
end
```

so later in your code instead of

```
json_log      =  {:replace_hash => @replace_hash}
logger.info json_log.to_json

json_log      =  {:outbound_text => @outbound_text}
logger.info  json_log.to_json

json_log      =  {:xtest => @xtest_array}
logger.info  json_log.to_json

json_log      =  {:tags => @tag_hash.keys, :last_response => @last_response }
logger.info   json_log.to_json
```

you will have

```
@logger = MyLogger.new(logger, self)
@logger.log(:replace_hash)
@logger.log(:outbound_text)
@logger.log(:xtest)
@logger.log(:tag_hash.keys, :last_response)
```

and instead of

```
json_log = {:conversation => {:inbound_text => @inbound_text, :outbound_text => @outbound_text}}
logger.debug json_log.to_s
```

you will have

```
@logger.log_with_prefix(:conversation, :inbound_text, :outbound_text)
```

Comment: Thanks...is my approach to logging odd?  I would have thought there would be already a gem or standard way to solve this....I used json because one of the logging solutions I have been using was supposed to be able to search and parse logs

Comment: I'm trying to follow are your methods converting the symbol and assigning it the value of the corresponding instance variable?

Comment: @Angela yes, `:tag_hash.keys` will also invoke keys method